# Как получить учасников беседы vk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Я хочу реализовать проверку на "админа" в беседе и использую метод `messages.getConversationMembers` но когда я передаю параметр peer_id я получаю ошибку `[917] You don't have access to this chat` я так подозреваю это связано с тем что беседа не отображается в сообщениях сообщества, так как получить участников беседы? (P.s. Все настроено правильно в ключе выбран тип "сообщения" и в LongPoll тоже)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ оказался прост: Для использования этого метода ботом ему необходимо видать права администратора в беседе.